# what's required to make Polymer install and work without Node or NPM?

Tags: node.js, polymer

Polymer looks very good and I'd like to give it a try, however for our project, Node is not part of our platform and it cannot be.  What is required to make a Polymer project that does not require Node or NPM?

Answer (score 7):

Polymer does not require node or npm per se. We recommend using Bower (requires nodejs) to get elements because it handles the dependency management.

Alternatively, you can use git to fetch stuff. We have have a pull-all.sh script that gets you everything in a single checkout: http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/tooling-strategy.html#git

Moving forward, we're working on solutions to provide .zip files of element collections. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

To run polymer you need a basic web server. The web server can be in Node.js or in Python or any HTTP Web Server.